# Non-simultaneous intersections of $r = 4\cos\theta+1$ and $r = 2\cos\theta+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

$$r = 4\cos\theta+1$$
$$r = 2\cos\theta+1$$

This system has simultaneous solutions at $(1, \frac\pi2)$ and $(1, \frac{3\pi}2)$.  But looking at the graph, there are non-simultaneous intersections at $(3, 0)$ and the pole.  How can that be determined algebraically?  What is the general way of solving for non-simultaneous intersections?  Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: It seems like if you have $f(\theta)$ and $g(\theta)$ you need to solve for $f(\theta) = g(\theta)$ as well as $f(\theta) = -g(\theta+\pi)$.  Correct me if I am wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In polar coordinate functions, replacing $(r,\theta)$ by $(-r,\pi+\theta)$ does not make any difference.

So in this example,
$$r=4\cos \theta+1$$
$$-r=-2\cos \theta+1$$
$$\text{Then, }0=2\cos \theta+2$$
$$\theta = \pi\Rightarrow r=-3$$
Therefore $(-3,\pi)$(or $(3,0)$) are solutions.

(Please someone verify this)

Comment: You didn't do the replacement, did you?

Comment: Yes. The second equation has replaced by $(-r,\pi+\theta)$

Comment: You replaced $\theta$ with $\pi + \theta$?? I don't think that's right